# Force refresh on Blazorise DataGrid

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazorise

how do you force a refresh on a Blazorise DataGrid?  The scenario is a Page Size component changes the page size from 5 to 10 and the grid should be refreshed with the new Page Size.  Despite the grid being bound to PageSize, the ReadData event does not fire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I usually do it.

First, save event arguments for `OnReadData`

```
private DataGridReadDataEventArgs<Order> lastDataRead;
```

and

```
private async Task OnReadData( DataGridReadDataEventArgs<Order> e )
{
    lastDataRead = e; // save every time, so you can refresh later

    var result = await OrderApi.GetAllByUser( ... );

    ...

    StateHasChanged();
}
```

And then when you need to refresh just call `OnReadData`

```
await OnReadData( lastDataRead ?? new DataGridReadDataEventArgs<Order>( 0, 10, null ) );
```

Obviously, you would need to reapply event args with the page number and page size according to your scenario.

Comment: Thanks Mladen, I just did the same.  Works well.

Comment: This requires me to reload my data though. Suppose i have a button that makes a known change to the grid, i want to update it in place without having to also reload the full data. how can i trigger this update?